# Drupal 8 Access Denied

Tags: drupal-8

I've just taken a copy of my drupal 8 database from staging and loaded this on my development enviroment.

I now get access denied when I try to login /admin

Can't find any information on why.

**Update**

Seems to be something to do with a twig service where the urlGenerator is not being implemented. Still no luck fixing this.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with this little information? What does your environment look like, which steps did you take to install this database. What permissions do you have within your environment, etc.

Comment: Database replication was command line using mysq dump and mysql to restore. Permissions are all correcy. This was all working fine before I took a snap shot of the staging db and installed. @Glubus

Answer (score 0):

In hoster`s panel try find "IP address:" settings and change it from "Dedicated IP" (this option can have dependant "This site processes direct requests to a dedicated IP address" tick) to "Shared IP".

Answer (score -1):

Without doing login in your site, you can not access the admin screen.

For example : If your site is justprogrammer.com and you try to open link justprogrammer.com/admin without login then you are not able to access the page. Before accessing the admin link, you first need to login using justprogrammer.com/user.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot just access any `/admin/*` pages on drupal without logging in. For that you have to login from `/user/login` put in the username and relevant password then you can access the admin side if you really have admin role and actually logging in from admin account. 
If you don't know the password for admin simply reset them to whatever you want by this drush command.
`drush upwd --password="YourPassword" 1`

`1` is user id of admin.